# How to recreate this colour change on Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, black, white

I had previously edited this photo, however the file was corrupted and I cannot remember how I edited it, and I can't recreate the same effect of the colour change. I am wanting to recreate the black and white art on the right, any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you
 [[image]

Comment: Well it just looks like some sort of desaturation. But the bricks in the background look like they are *more* saturated than before. Maybe you used a mask? Are you aware that the two images aren't exactly the same? The brick pattern is different.

Comment: Yes, I added a layer which is the graffiti, and it is what I am attempting to recreate the same colour and effect

Comment: I am unable to get the same texture on the tongue

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. To me the main difference is that the left image is in color and the right image is monochrome. I can see some "splatter" on the tongues too, but it doesn't look like graffiti to me. More like a piece of paper glued to a wall. Maybe you mean *threshold* or *posterize*?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply switch to the channels palette, turn all but one of them not visible, and when you decide which you like, delete the other channels and then flatten the image and ensure the mode is correct (RGB or greyscale).

However: the black on the tongue looks more like a magic-wand selection; the brick background still has color in it.

In this particular case, the blue and red are very well isolated, so you simply "select color" for each, copy and paste to new layer to isolate, and then desaturate the color etc. etc.